# Merge elements in an array

Tags: java, comparative-review

I have written two different codes for merging (merging with costs) and I want to know if I can make optimizations to run faster.

#### merge1:

```
 private static long merge(List<Integer> array, int[] res, int start, int mid, int end) {

        int i = start; // index of left subarray
        int j = mid; // index of right subarray
        int k = start; //index of mid

        long inversions = 0;

        for (int r = start; r <= end; r++) {

            if ((j > end) || (i < mid && array.get(i) <= array.get(j))) {
                res[r] = array.get(i);
                i++;
            } else {

                if (i < mid) {

                    if (array.get(i) - array.get(j) > 1) {

                        inversions += 3 * (mid - i);
                    } else {
                        int s;
                        s = MostRightSmallestElement.search(array, i, mid - 1);
                        inversions += 2 * (s - i + 1);
                        inversions += 3 * (mid - (s + 1));
                    }

                }
                res[r] = array.get(j);
                j++;

            }
        }



       //Copy the remaining elements of left subarray  (if there are any) to res
        while (i <= mid - 1) {
            res[k++] = array.get(i++);
        }

        //Copy the remaining elements of right subarray  (if there are any) to res
        while (j <= end) {
            res[k++] = array.get(j++);
        }

        //Copy back the merged elements to original array
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            array.set(i, res[i]);
        }

        return inversions;

    }
```

#### merge2:

```
private static long merge(List<Integer> array, int[] res, int start, int mid, int end) {

        int i = start; // index of left subarray
        int j = mid; // index of right subarray
        int k = start; //index of mid

        long inversions = 0;


        while( ( i <mid) && (j <= end )) {

            if( array.get(i) <=  array.get(j)){
                res[k++] = array.get(i++);
            }
            else {

                if (i != mid) {

                    if (array.get(i) - array.get(j) > 1) {

                        inversions =  inversions + 3 * (mid - i);

                    } else {
                          int s;
                        s = MostRightSmallestElement.search(array, i, mid - 1);
                        inversions =  inversions +  2 * (s - i + 1);
                        inversions =  inversions +  3 * (mid - (s + 1));
                    }
          }
                res[k++] = array.get(j++);

        }
        }

       //Copy the remaining elements of left subarray  (if there are any) to res
        while (i <= mid - 1) {
            res[k++] = array.get(i++);
        }

        //Copy the remaining elements of right subarray  (if there are any) to res
        while (j <= end) {
            res[k++] = array.get(j++);
        }

        //Copy back the merged elements to original array
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            array.set(i, res[i]);
        }

        return inversions;

    }
```

Any ideas how I can optimize the code? I count the inversions but the general
idea of merging is the same.

Comment: @leaderq Did you intend to [withdraw this question](/review/suggested-edits/74940)?

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/160076/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

***comparative-review*:**
In both variants, both "traversing indices" get compared to their (respective upper) limit in each traversal of the "proper merge loop".
While "the copy2res-loops" should never execute in `merge1`, the "`res`-index" gets compared to its limit right from the start.
In `merge2`, the "proper merge loop" isn't traversed as often.
Exactly one of the copy2res-loops should be traversed for the same total.

remarks:

- `merge()` isn't [doc-comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)ed.
  the comments for `start`&`mid` might as well be [`@param`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@param)s,
  `index of mid` looks off,
  all three may be `final`.
- Both `subarray`s include their start - excluding `end` would be consistent.
- I don't get the *inversion counting* - lack of documentation doesn't help.

Speed-up:

- beware memory hierarchy effects
  old school complexity analysis assumes uniform memory access time - far from what I'd want to pay and wait for.
- don't copy back and fro. Use the auxiliary sequence as the/one source for the next pass.
- don't convert between `Integer` and `int` time and again.
- when using `List`s, avoid relying on the "random accessors" to be fast
  (implementing [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) is a hint - read backwards, its doc recommends to "always")
  use `ListIterator`s to iterate `List`s  (note how they (optionally) support [set(newValue)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-))
- don't time-consumingly ponder/implement variants unless you

  - *established* it matters
  - *fixed* a *measure* for *good enough*
- converting to arrays and never looking back (with the possible exception of a terminating conversion/copy back) is an option promising sequential storage and allowing [bulk operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). With `List`s, [operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) on [sublists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) *may* be more efficient.
- Most JREs allow a peek at [their implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) (have a look at `java.util.Arrays`, too).